# Java - changing a variable through pass-by-value

Tags: java, pass-by-value

So I've read about the pass-by-value nature of Java and I've tried to change my variable after passing it to a function by having the function return the variable again. I didn't succeed in that.

My code

```
public class Logic {
    private int position;

    public class Logic(){
        position = 1;
    }

    public void appendPosition(){
        position = calculatePosition(position);
    }
}
```

This is the barebones code. I call this method from an instance of `Logic` which is instantiated in another class:

```
public class MainLogic {
    ILogic L;

    public MainLogic(ILogic L){
        this.L = L;
    }

    public void start(){
        L.appendPosition();
    }
}
```

Through repeated debugging I find to my dismay that the `position` variable does not change at all. The `position` variable passed to `calculatePosition` changes fine, as expected. What am I missing? I've tried making the variable `public` and `static`.

calculatePosition

```
private int calculatePosition(int position){
        position += 6;
        if(snakeLocations[position]>0) {
            position -= 6;
        }
        else if(ladderLocations[position]>0) {
            position += 6;
        }
        return position;
    }

private final int[] snakeLocations = new int[] {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,0,0,0,13,0,0,0,0,0,19,0,0,0,0,0};
private final int[] ladderLocations = new int[] {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,11,0,0,0,15,0,0,0,0,20,0,0,0,0};
```

Comment: And what is `calculatePosition(int)`?

Comment: Could you post the `calculatePosition` method?

Comment: I updated the OP with the method. For what it's worth I found that it does seem to change the position value.

Comment: Presumably `snakeLocations[7]` is `> 0` so you subtract `6` and the value doesn't change.

Comment: Lightning fast reply! I'm pretty sure that that is not the case. I updated the OP with those values too. Positition starts at 1 always, and this happens at first try.

Comment: @Gudmundur Yes, but your first line adds 6. `+ 6` and `- 6` is `0`.

Comment: Try creating a local variable to catch the value of position and use that instead. i.e. `calculatePosition(int position)` then `int p = position;` and use `p` instead of position throughout the method

Comment: The if condition is false on first try I'm pretty sure, so it doesn't reach that -6 on first try. It stays at 7.

Comment: Note that it's poor form to have a local variable and an instance variable with the same name.

Comment: @CalvinP. This is interesting. The new variable, p, doesn't show up in the debugger. Does that mean anything?

Comment: @CalvinP. - No, he should change the name of `position` in the prototype parm list for `calculatePosition` and not reference `position` *at all* inside that method.  I don't believe that this is causing the problem, but it makes it hard to think about and debug.

Comment: It means you're not looking in the right place in the debugger.

Comment: @HotLicks I swear to god when I hover over the variable it says "not defined in current context" even though the breakpoint is after its declaration

Comment: It's not "defined" until a value is assigned to it.  (Change it to be the method parm rather than a local variable.)

Comment: Your classname is Logic, but you instantiate ILogic. So the last code is from some SampleLogic which implements ILogic?

Comment: Your public class logic contains something which reminds me of a constructor, but with the keyword 'class' inside - it will not compile. You should test your simplified test code, before posting it,

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Logic {
private int position;

public Logic(){
    position = 1;
}
//to get position.....................

public int getPosition(){
    return this.position;
}
public void appendPosition(){
    position = calculatePosition(position);
}
private int calculatePosition(int position){
    position += 6;
    if(snakeLocations[position]>0) {
        position -= 6;
    }
    else if(ladderLocations[position]>0) {
        position += 6;
    }
    return position;
}

private final int[] snakeLocations = 
        new int[] {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,0,0,0,13,0,0,0,0,0,19,0,0,0,0,0};
private final int[] ladderLocations = 
        new int[] {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,11,0,0,0,15,0,0,0,0,20,0,0,0,0};
}

//next class

public class MainLogic {

Logic L;

public MainLogic(Logic L){
    this.L = L;
}

public void start(){
    L.appendPosition();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Logic L = new Logic();
    MainLogic ml = new MainLogic(L);
    System.out.println(ml.L.getPosition());
    ml.start();
    System.out.println(ml.L.getPosition());
}

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's read your code.

```
// There is a logic class.
public class Logic { 

    // So Logic has a position. it starts with zero.    
    private int position;

    // Logic also has an inner class, also called Logic.
    public class Logic(){
        position = 1;
        // When a new Logic().Logic() is created, the instance
        // variable of the parent instance gets set to one. WHAT?!?
    }
    // ... lots of code
}
```

So, It's a bit like that Yo Dawg! meme - I heard you like Logic, so we've put A logic instance into your Logic instance so you can Logic while your Logic.

You probably want a **constructor**.

```
// So this is Logic.
public class Logic {

    private int position;

    // When an Logic instance is created, position starts with 1.
    public Logic(){
        this.position = 1;
    }
```

Ok. So we're not talking about Yo Dawg Memes. 
So Let's talk pass by value.

Pass-by-value means classes are like very egotistic children: You can't play with their toys, unless they tell you so.

This is a **good thing**® since this means only the owning instance is allowed to change their private state. Trust me, it prevents quite a bit of havoc.

One way to allow the outside world to actually change the state is by using **query and mutator methods**. Back in the day, we used to call them **getter and setter**, but that sounds too simple, so software architects will usually use the fancier term.

But... **all of this doesn't really apply since `calculatePosition()` is defined at Logic.** Oops.

Let's try this:

1. Renaming some instance variables
2. Be a bit verbose to help the debugger. baby steps.

(Also, dropping a few jokes to fish for upvotes).

```
public class Logic {

    private int position = 1;

    public void appendPosition(){
        // When debugging strange stuff, 
        // keep each step simple. 
        // Is calculatePosition working as it should?
        int newPosition = calculatePosition(this.position);
        this.position = newPosition;
    }

    // Always use parameters as final. It's good karma.
    // You don't NEED to declare them as final,
    // but let's try to be EXTRA clear.
    private int calculatePosition(final int targetPosition){

        // Yes, make as much as you can immutable
        // You'll save a ton of mental bandwidth.
        final int localCopy = targetPosition +6;

        if(snakeLocations[localCopy]>0) {
            return (localCopy -6);
            // Don't force the maintenance programmer to 
            // read all your stuff. Return often, return early. 
            // This isn't Cc++, where you need to 
            // actually free your reference/pointers, 
            // so there's no point enforcing a single return.
        }
        if(ladderLocations[localCopy]>0) {
            return (localCopy+6);
        }
        return localCopy;
    }
}
```

So... Did this worked as it should?

Comment: Haha woops that was a typo on my part - it's a constructor on my end.

Comment: @Gudmundur: Where is `calculatePosition()` defined? in Logic?

Comment: Yes it's defined there

Answer (score -2):

I found the answer. This is often my mistake in posting here. I try to strip down my code as much as possible to ease the work for you guys, but sometimes the problem lies outside of the scope of what I provide due to a lack of understanding, or oversight, on my part.

I was actually calling `MainLogic` from two levels above:

```
public mainFrame() {
        initComponents();
        logic = Factory.getMainLogic();
    }
```

where

```
public static class Factory {
    public MainLogic getMainLogic(){
        PlayerLogic pL = new PlayerLogic();
        ImageLogic iL = new ImageLogic();
        DieLogic dL = new DieLogic();
        MainLogic mainLogic = new MainLogic(pL,iL,dL);

        return mainLogic;
    }
}
```

I forgot I had accidentally put `Factory` as `static`. My sincerest apologies for wasting your time.